# System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 2, Actual: 3

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests, assertexception

Earlier this is working with 3 but due to few modifications to this class, Now it is not working. What would be the problem if i change  like

```
System.assertEquals(lAccrSaleConShare.size(), 2);
```

Comment: This is the whole point of a test method.  According to the person that wrote the test, you should be getting 3.  This means any code that calls this method after your changes, will get a different result.  Is that a bad thing? Only you can answer that.

Comment: Yeah that will not be good. But is is working fine in devfull org. I getting error in UAT. Same code in both orgs. Not even single line difference.

Comment: This is why testing magic numbers is brittle, and also why using assertion messages is very important.

Comment: How can i query list size which is in test class? I just want to check how many records are fetching the list.   i want to checkout this:            lAccrSaleConShare = [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM Accreditation_Sales_Contact__Share WHERE ParentId =: accrSaleCon.Id];

Answer (score 2):

Don't follow the example set by this code.

- The syntax is `system.assertEquals(expected_value, actual_value, message)`.

  - In the assertions above, `expected_value` and `actual_value` are flipped.
  - While the `message` argument is optional, it is *highly* recommended and might have helped you here.
- When using magic numbers in your unit tests, you can give them more meaning by making them *constants*. Most of my test classes have a line `static final Integer RECORD_COUNT = Limits.getLimitQueries() + 1`, which you could use in place of `3`.
- You aren't even testing the `setManualShareAfterInsert` method. You're testing a trigger somewhere, which you haven't shared with us.
- Same goes for the `setManualShareAfterUpdate` method.

I can't tell you how to get your unit test working. I can't even tell if your code should work as advertised. But you might have some luck by working on Separation Of Concerns. You could break out a few discrete tasks and verify they work as expected, then build on that. The key to *unit* testing is to test small *units* of code.

I have found trying to build on top of code that tries to do dozens of things in one method is just not tenable. Here's a start for how I would refactor:

```
public static Set<Id> pluckIds(String field, List<SObject> records)
{
    Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
    for (SObject record : records)
        ids.add((Id)record.get(field));
    ids.remove(null);
    return ids;
}
public static Map<Id, Accreditation__c> getAccreditations(List<Accreditation_Sales_Contact__c>  records)
{
    return new Map<Id, Accreditation>([
        SELECT Id, Name, Account__r.Partner_Community_User_Role_ID__c
        FROM Accreditation__c
        WHERE Id IN :pluckIds('Accreditation__c', records)
    ]);
    // if you query the Account__r.Partner_Community_User_Role_ID__c field,
    // you don't even need to query Account at all, just reference this way
}
```

Anyway, that's probably not the answer you were looking for, but hopefully it will help you to some extent.

Comment: Even if i keep that line static final Integer RECORD_COUNT = Limits.getLimitQueries() + 1   it firing error : actual 2 expected 101.    How to check this query list to check how many records are in list. I am not able to query as it is sharing Object and which id i need to pass?

Comment: Again, keep in mind that `expected_value` and `actual_value` are reversed. It's expecting 3. I don't know why it would create 3 shares per record. It looks like it should only be creating one. And your unit test doesn't touch this method directly, only the trigger...